# Make property readonly in derived class

Tags: c#, properties, overriding, access-modifiers

I'm overriding a property in my derived class that I would like to make it readonly.  The C# compiler won't let me change the access modifiers, so it must stay public.

What's the best way to do this?  Should I just throw an `InvalidOperationException` in `set { }`?

Comment: We need more context I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having the setter throw an `InvalidOperationException` in a derived class violates the [Liskov Subsitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Essentially makes the usage of the setter contextual to the type of the base class which essentially eliminates the value of polymorphism.

Your derived class must respect the contract of it's base class.  If the setter is not appropriate in all circumstances then it doesn't belong on the base class.

One way to work around this is to break the hierarchy up a little bit.

```
class C1 { 
  public virtual int ReadOnlyProperty { get; } 
}
class C2 { 
  public sealed override int ReadOnlyProperty { 
    get { return Property; }
  }
  public int Property {
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
  }
}
```

Your type you're having problems with could inherit `C1` in this scenario and the rest could switch to derive from `C2`

Comment: So if the base class has an `IsReadOnly` property and throws its own exception then it's OK?  That's how the `NameObjectCollectionBase` > `NameValueCollection` > `HttpValueCollection` inheritance works, which is used by a `Page`'s `Request.Param`.  I understand the reasoning behind the principle, but in the case of `NameObjectCollectionBase`, it contradicts your statement: `If the setter is not appropriate in all circumstances then it doesn't belong on the base class.`  Unfortunately I am using a .NET class which didn't implement this (for good reason).  I think it makes sense in my case.

Comment: @Nelson having the base class have `IsReadOnly` is ... a compromise at best. Personally I think it's a terrible pattern and BCL would`ve been much better if the collections were properly divided into mutable and read-only interfaces / types.

Comment: Ok, so I'll get more specific.  I am deriving from ASP.NET's `ListView`.  Let's call it `MyCustomList`.  I want all the features/templates of `ListView`, but let `MyCustomList` handle getting the data, assigning `DataSource/Id`, and preventing `DataSource/Id` from being changed.  I think throwing an exception is a good compromise versus re-implementing all the `ListView` functionality myself.

Comment: Maybe I should be extending `ObjectDataSource` (or similar) instead, but also want to have some default templates in place.

Comment: @Nelson, I think going the `ObjectDataSource` route sounds more reasonable.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I agree with you... :)  It's a tiny bit more work every time, but much more flexible/extensible.

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the original implementation and return the base implementation:

```
class Foo
{
    private string _someString;
    public virtual string SomeString 
    {
        get { return _someString; }
        set { _someString = value; }
    }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    public new string SomeString 
    { 
        get { return base.SomeString; }
        private set { base.SomeString = value; }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            f.SomeString = "whatever";  // works
            Bar b = new Bar();
            b.SomeString = "Whatever";  // error
        }
    }
}
```

However,. as Jared has alluded to, this is kind of a weird situation.  Why don't you make your setter private or protected in the base class to begin with?

Comment: Except that if you do " Foo f2 = b; f.SomeString = "eeba geeba!"; " from your example, the compiler lets you.

Comment: @mjfgates: I'm guessing you mean `Foo f = new Bar(); f.SomeString = "blah"`?  That's the reason I didn't go this route.  I can't change the base class since I'm deriving from a standard ASP.NET web control.

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote.  In that case you are calling Foo.SomeString because SomeString is not polymorphic in Bar, it is hiding the Foo implementation.

Comment: @Ed: I was referring to what mjfgates wrote (even though indirectly it was about what you wrote).  Anyway, I understand how this works and don't want two implementations that work differently depending on what type you are working with.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that responding on my phone.  I agree 100% that this is not optimal.  The problem arises from the initial request though.  If you make a bad design choice you will likely make more bad design choices down the road as a direct result.  I would not try to hide the setter at all and avoid breaking the interface,

Answer (score 1):

I think i this situation the better solution is new keyword

```
public class Aclass {        
    public int ReadOnly { get; set; }
}

public class Bclass : Aclass {        
    public new int ReadOnly { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: With the new keyword you can hide the base get and set accessors

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to hide your base class' public members in C#, because somebody could take an instance of your derived class, stuff it into a reference to the base class, and access the property that way.

If you want to make a class that provided most, but not all, of the interface of another class, you'll have to use aggregation. Don't inherit from the "base class," just include one in the "derived" one by value, and provide your own member functions for the portions of the "base class" functionality you wish to expose. Those functions can then just forward the calls on to the appropriate "base class" functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the property with new keyword and don provide the Setter method in the derived class. This will hide the base class property as well, however as mjfgates mentioned one can still access the base class property by assigning it to a base class instance. Thats polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where the pattern you describe is justifiable.  For example, it may be helpful to have an abstract class `MaybeMutableFoo`, from which are derived subtypes `MutableFoo` and `ImmutableFoo`.  All three classes include an `IsMutable` property, and methods `AsMutable()`, `AsNewMutable()`, and `AsImmutable()`.

In that situation, it would be entirely proper for the `MaybeMutableFoo` to expose a read-write property, if its contract explicitly specifies that the setter may not work unless `IsMutable` returns true.  An object which has a field of type `MaybeMutableFoo` that happens to hold an instance of `ImmutableFoo` could be perfectly happy with that instance unless or until it had to write to it, whereupon it would replace the field with an object returned via `AsMutable()` and then use it as a mutable foo (it would know it was mutable, since it had just replaced it).  Having `MaybeMutableFoo` include a setter would avoid the need to do any future typecasts on the field once it was made to refer to a mutable instance.

The best way to allow for such a pattern is to avoid implementing virtual or abstract properties, but instead implement non-virtual properties whose getters and setters chain to virtual or abstract methods.  If one has a base class

```
public class MaybeMutableFoo
{
    public string Foo {get {return Foo_get();} set {Foo_set(value);}
    protected abstract string Foo_get();
    protected abstract void Foo_set(string value};
}
```

then a derived class `ImmutableFoo` may declare:

```
    new public string Foo {get {return Foo_get();}
```

to make its `Foo` property be read-only without interfering with the ability to code overrides for the abstract `Foo_get()` and `Foo_set()` methods.  Note that the read-only replacement of `Foo` doesn't change the behavior of the property get; the read-only version chains to same the base-class method as the base-class property did.  Doing things this way will ensure that there's one patch point for changing the property getter, and one for changing the setter, and those patch points won't change even if the property itself gets redefined.